# Are independent couples keeps their independent in conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

This is a part of an identity that I need to prove in my homework (that
 is not the identity itself).

$\mathcal{Y}=\{0,1\}$, $(X_{1},Y_{1}),(X_{2},Y_{2})$  are drawn independently from some distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$

So I can assume that $(X_{1},Y_{1}),(X_{2},Y_{2})$ are independent, but I can't assume anything about $P(X_{1}),P(X_{2})$

My question is if the following equation is correct:
$P(Y_{1}=y_{1},Y_{2}=y_{2} \mid X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2})=P(Y_{1}=y_{1} \mid X_{1}=x_{1})\cdot P(Y_{2}=y_{2} \mid X_{2}=x_{2})$

Is there proof for that equation? or else, is there a counterexample for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also discrete,

\begin{align}
&\mathsf{P}(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2\mid X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2) \\[0.5em]
&\qquad=\frac{\mathsf{P}(Y_1=y_1,Y_2=y_2,X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)}{\mathsf{P}(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2)} \\
&\qquad=\frac{\mathsf{P}(Y_1=y_1,X_1=x_1)\mathsf{P}(Y_2=y_2,X_2=x_2)}{\mathsf{P}(X_1=x_1)\mathsf{P}(X_2=x_2)} \\[0.5em]
&\qquad=\mathsf{P}(Y_1=y_1\mid X_1=x_1)\mathsf{P}(Y_2=y_2\mid X_2=x_2).
\end{align}

Comment: why is $P(X_1=x1, X_2=x_2) = P(X_1=x1)P(X_2=x_2)$?

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent...

Comment: how can you assume that? the couples are independent but you don't know that about $X_1,X_2$

Comment: I don't assume that. It follows from the independence of $(Y_1,X_1)$ and $(Y_2,X_2)$...